# How to update a UserControl size which will never come in to view (only be printed)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resize, refresh

I create a `Usercontrol` in code which get's a `Datacontext`
and than get printed but i need to refresh the `Usercontrol` so it get resized (Stretch to fit the Content) but i don't know how i should do this

my Code

```
var view = new DruckV();
view.DataContext = this;
// now i need to resize it
```

i tried

```
view.UpdateLayout();// width and height will remain by 0,0
```

than i can call my Printer

```
var printer = new Printer();
printer.Print(view);
```

so how should i do this because i can't use

```
view.Measure(UnknownSize);
view.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), UnknownSize));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 3.5 .net framework you can create a container for the control and perform Measure/Arrange for infinity size (or if control has a dynamic dimensions that depends on container size - set maximum allowed size to the container):

```
var panel = new StackPanel();
//panel.MaxWidth = 100; //if you control has dynamic sizing
//panel.MaxHeight = 100;
panel.Children.Add(view);
var infinitySize = double.PositiveInfinity,double.PositiveInfinity;
panel.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
panel.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, panel.DesiredSize.Width, panel.DesiredSize.Width));
view.UpdateLayout();
```

Unfortunately on .net 4.x this solution doesn't worked for me and only way I have found to force update controls size is create new Window with container (same as described above) and show this window outside a display screen (set `Window.Left =-1000;`)

BTW: in case of rendering by invisible window, size of the rendering control can't be larger than monitors screen size, and to render huge controls you have to perform `ScaleTransform`on it.

Comment: i using `.Net 4 Client` and your [Solution](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/csharp/rendercontrolasbitmap/) works very well for me :)